# Vue: update a value in data() from import

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I have a file called `Authenticator.coffee`

```
...
# User
user =
    id: '123'
export { user }


# Auth change
auth = firebase.auth()
auth.onAuthStateChanged (u) => 
    console.log('Auth state changed ', u.uid)
    user.id = u.uid
```

... and in `Page.vue` I'd like to display the `id`:

```
...
{{ uid }}
...


<script>
    import { user } from '../providers/Authenticator.coffee';
    export default {
        data() {
            return {            
                uid: user.id
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The initial value is displayed, but **changes are not**. Changes do arrive, I can see the 'Auth state changed' message being logged with the `id`.

Will changes in imported values not be reflected in `data()`?
How can I do this otherwise?

Extra: Can I just not do `{{ user.id }}` in the `template` and have the `script` only consist of the `import`?

Comment: You shouldn't access `u.uid` without checking if `u` is `null` first (happens on logout for example). `uid` is a primitive and copied not passed by reference, `user` is also a plain object but maybe it will work if you pass that (not sure if Vue magically makes it observable when you pass it in)

Comment: If you want to leverage on Vue reactivity system you have to pass your data to the component as props

Comment: @Dominic fair point, thank you

Comment: @Plastic as far as I know, not necessarily. As Abounegm said, this works if I pass an object rather than a primitive. I could also access the Vue instance and get / set it's data() with something like this.$root.user.id. Even accessing / changing data on the Vue prototype might work, but I'm not really sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *uid* is most probably a string, it is copied and not shared by reference. For the authentication to update the value in the component, pass the user object itself so that the same object is shared between both files.